# How to see if two integers in an array are the same

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Good day everyone.
I'm not quite sure on how to check for the same elements in an array example.
%java stuff 4 6 1 2 3 1 
/* Now that there are two ones in the array it should pump out "Yes! The same!"*/ 
I do realize however that I can take the first value in the array and check that with a for loop and then so on and so forth.
I'm just not quite confident on the syntax yet.
So far I've tried putting up an if case for checking it put it doesn't work. Can anyone please be so kind and help me understand my project a little bit better?
P.s. I'm open towards all improvements of this question.

```
  public class seeIT
    {
      public static void main (String[] args)
      {
       int N = args.length;   
       int [] a =   new int[N];

        boolean flag = false; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        }
      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for(int j = i +1; j < N; j++)
{ if(a[i] == a[j])
   { flag = true; 
} else
  {
      System.out.print("correct, there are no numbers that are the same here");}



        }

    }
    }
```

- I created the boolean flag because, again, I realize that I need to check whether or not the statement is true or not. 
  Thank you all for kind answers and have a nice day.
  Josef.

Comment: I didn't see any `if` condition here.

Comment: You have 3 opening braces but 4 closing ones. Something is missing.

Comment: As you said the naive but still effective approach would be to loop through the array and compare the current value with all that follow it. Should be easy to implement if you know some programming basics. A better approach might be to sort the array first or use some kind of mapping.

Comment: Woops. Allow me to edit the code.

Comment: Is this school assignment ?

Comment: @rajuGT Nope, I'm just trying to learn some programming in my free time. Thought this would be a fun little assignment so I can understand arrays better.

Comment: I appreciate that. Good (y) I asked because students put up there assignments in SO.

Comment: Hint: once you've found 2 equal numbers, you can use the `break` keyword to exit the loop (useful if you have a long array and the first 2 elements are the same, you will spare a lot of processing time).

Answer (score 1):

Add the elements to the set (HashSet), If the set.add returns false on the element, which means that element is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

There are some flaws in your code:
This reads always the first element of the array: `a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`, the `boolean` is never evaluated and the variable `N` is unnecessary (and in Java local variables should start with lower case).

I think, this is what you want:

```
int[] a = new int[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            System.out.print("same " + a[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

But a better way (as already mentioned) would be to use a HashSet. That way you do not even have to convert Strings to int. Just compare the values using equals() insted of ==. The code is even more simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        java.util.Set<String> dbl = new java.util.HashSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < args.length; j++) {
                if (args[i].equals(args[j])) {
                    dbl.add(args[i]);
                } 
            }
        }

        System.out.print("" + dbl.size() + " figure(s) appear more than once.");
        java.util.Iterator<String> it = dbl.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("   " + it.next());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` would be the class to use for this kind of problem, however it doesn't hurt to do it "manually" if you're learning. Here are some comments on your code:

```
a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

I assume you meant

```
a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

otherwise you would be putting `args[0]` at every position in `a`.

```
if(a[i] == a[j]) {
    flag = true;
} else {
  System.out.print("correct, there are no numbers that are the same here");
}
```

You are printing the result too soon - before you can know it. At this point you just know whether two particular elements are the same (and you correctly set the flag if they are), but you have to wait until the loops finish to know that there were no such elements in the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest using a `HashSet` since it would take care of all repetition checking for you. But since you are in a learning stage, I will rather stick with your approach here.

I suggest putting your array checking logic in a separate method that returns a `boolean`. This way, you can return `true` as soon as you find a repeated number (`return` immediately exits a method), thereby avoiding uselessly iterating over the rest of the array. This also makes your code reusable.

This gives the following code. I also did some reformatting to make the code more readable, and I corrected a typo that makes your code repeatedly add the first argument into the `int` array.

```
public class SeeIT {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = args.length;   
    int[] a = new int[n];

    boolean flag = false; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    boolean repeats = hasRepetitions(a);
    if (repeats) {
      System.out.println("There is at least one repeated number.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("correct, there are no numbers that are the same here");
    }
  }

  private static boolean hasRepetitions(int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
          return true; 
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

I hope this will help...

Cheers,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SeeIT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int [] a = new int[]{1,2,5,4,3,7,2};

            boolean flag = false;
            for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j< a.length; j++){
                         if(a[j] == a[i]){
                           if(j != i) {
                            flag = true;
                             }
                      }
                    }
            }

            if(flag == true){
                    System.out.println("Duplicates");

            }else{
                    System.out.println("not duplicate");
            }



    }

}
}
```

This for-loop should do the trick. It's a double for-loop which iterates in the same array.